# Process web page in JavaScript/browser and inserting into database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, firefox

I'm processing URLs with my program,

Basically what it does is, `file_get_contents($url)` to get web content and attach a JavaScript code at the bottom which processes the HTML source for the biggest image and inserts into the database by ajax.

The problem is I have to instantiate Firefox browser for the processing. I really don't need Firefox to render the page visually and other workings. All I want is for my script to do its job.

So is there a way to use Firefox's HTML/CSS and JavaScript engine without having to call the entire browser?

Comment: is this a plugin or just a script/website somewhere?

Comment: Heard of PhantomJS? Http://phantomjs.org

Comment: @bensonsearch not a plugin, just a script attached to webpage.

Comment: As Paul already mentioned one, there are many headless browsers out there, you can use Selenium for example if you want to stick with firefox http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/